# Use Bearer Token Authentication for API and OpenId authentication for MVC on the same application project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, openid, owin

I am trying to use both OpenId and Bearer token authentication on my application through Identity Server.

The problem currently is that once I have authenticated the user, I still need to get a bearer token to be able to call any action methods for my Asp.Net MVC application.

Here is my startup file for the application

```
 public class Startup
{
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
     {            
         AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
         JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
         {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
         });

         app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
         {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44301/identity",
            ClientId = "baseballStats",
            Scope = "openid profile roles baseballStatsApi",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/",
            ResponseType = "id_token token",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                {
                    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
                                 new Uri(n.Options.Authority + "/connect/userinfo"),
                                 n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);

                    var userInfo = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();

                    // create new identity and set name and role claim type
                    var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                       n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
                        Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName,
                        Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                    userInfo.Claims.ToList().ForEach(c => nid.AddClaim(new Claim(c.Item1, c.Item2)));

                    // keep the id_token for logout
                    nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                    // add access token for sample API
                    nid.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                    // keep track of access token expiration
                    nid.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(n.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn)).ToString()));

                    // add some other app specific claim
                    nid.AddClaim(new Claim("app_specific", "some data"));

                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                        nid,
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                }
            }
         });



         app.UseResourceAuthorization(new AuthorizationManager());

         app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
         {
             Authority = "https://localhost:44301/identity",
             RequiredScopes = new[] { "baseballStatsApi" }
         });

         var config = new HttpConfiguration();
         config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
         app.UseWebApi(config);           
     }
}
```

**I would like to restrict bearer token authentication to my api urls only, and use openID auth for everthing else. Is there a way to do that?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I found some information on the following post

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/487

The github repo that implements the concepts discussed in the link can be found here

https://github.com/B3nCr/IdentityServer-Sample/blob/master/B3nCr.Communication/Startup.cs

Basically you need to map the api url to a different configuration using app.Map(). In my case, I changed my startup file to look like this.

```
 public class Startup
{
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
     {
         AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
         JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

         app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
         {
             AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
         });

         var openIdConfig = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
         {
             Authority = "https://localhost:44301/identity",
             ClientId = "baseballStats",
             Scope = "openid profile roles baseballStatsApi",
             RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/",
             ResponseType = "id_token token",
             SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",                 
             UseTokenLifetime = false,
             Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
             {
                 SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                 {
                     var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
                                  new Uri(n.Options.Authority + "/connect/userinfo"),
                                  n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);

                     var userInfo = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();

                     // create new identity and set name and role claim type
                     var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
                         Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName,
                         Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                     userInfo.Claims.ToList().ForEach(c => nid.AddClaim(new Claim(c.Item1, c.Item2)));

                     // keep the id_token for logout
                     nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                     // add access token for sample API
                     nid.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                     // keep track of access token expiration
                     nid.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(n.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn)).ToString()));

                     // add some other app specific claim
                     nid.AddClaim(new Claim("app_specific", "some data"));

                     n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                         nid,
                         n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

                     n.Request.Headers.SetValues("Authorization ", new string[] { "Bearer ", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken });
                 }
             }
         };

         app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIdConfig);

         app.UseResourceAuthorization(new AuthorizationManager());

         app.Map("/api", inner =>
         {
             var bearerTokenOptions = new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
             {
                 Authority = "https://localhost:44301/identity",
                 RequiredScopes = new[] { "baseballStatsApi" }
             };

             inner.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(bearerTokenOptions);
             var config = new HttpConfiguration();
             config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
             inner.UseWebApi(config);
         });                                                 
     }
}
```

That solved my problem. I can now access the MVC pages with cookies based authentication, and call the API with bearer token authentication.

Comment: What Nuget Packages you have used for this below method app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIdConfig);
app.UseResourceAuthorization(new AuthorizationManager());
inner.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication