# How to Implement Both OAuth2 (Bearer Token) and OpenID Connect Authentication in a .NET 6 Project Using Azure AD?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization

I have a web app (which needs a user login) and web api (which just needs a bearer token) and these are so small I would like to merge them into one project with different controllers. I am struggling with setting up `Program.cs` file and the controllers.

I am using .NET 6 and Azure AD as identity service.

This is what's in `WebApp Program.cs`:

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "WebApp:AzureAd")
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

And `WebApp:AzureAd` config contains following:

```
"WebApp": {
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "my-test.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "b1b0b0b0-1b1b-1b1b-1b1b-1b1b1b1b1b1b",
    "ClientId": "b1b0b0b0-1b1b-1b1b-1b1b-1b1b1b1b1b1b",
    "ClientSecret": "b1b0b0b0-1b1b-1b1b-1b1b-1b1b1b1b1b1b",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
  }
}
```

This is what's in `WebApi Program.cs` (Uses ClientCredential Authorization):

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration, "WebApi:AzureAd");
```

`WebApi:AzureAd` also has all the necessary settings like `WebApp`.

Here is my controller and how I want it to look like:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "WebApp")]
[HttpGet(nameof(AppMethod))]
public async Task<IActionResult> AppMethod()
{
   // Enters here after user authenticates themselves through Azure AD
}

[Authorize(Policy = "WebApi")]
[HttpPost(nameof(ApiMethod))]
public async Task<IActionResult> ApiMethod()
{
   // Enters here after receiving a valid Bearer token 
}
```

I have looked [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30881720/6742553) and [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0) but could not figure out a way to do it in .Net 6 with Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I found was as follows.

I added both Authentications to `Program.cs` file:

```
services
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "WebApi:AzureAd")
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

services
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "WebApp:AzureAd")
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

 // .......
 
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

And configured controllers like so:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpGet(nameof(AppMethod))]
public async Task<IActionResult> AppMethod()
{
   // Enters here after user authenticates themselves through Azure AD
}

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpPost(nameof(ApiMethod))]
public async Task<IActionResult> ApiMethod()
{
   // Enters here after receiving a valid Bearer token 
}
```

So this was the way for me to have a user login authentication through `AppMethod()` and bearer token validation through `ApiMethod()`.

I no longer receive a HTML file when sending a request to `ApiMethod()`